# Final layer of LSTM in Tensorflow MNIST example

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'm playing around with the Tensorflow LSTM example on the MNIST dataset.
What I don't understand is why in the final layer logistic regression is used. Isn't the last output of the LSTM network a better estimator than using the outputs of the previous 'timesteps'? How could I just use the last output of the LSTM network for classification?

```py
#  Copyright 2016 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
#  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#  limitations under the License.

"""
This example builds rnn network for mnist data.
Borrowed structure from here: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3%20-%20Neural%20Networks/recurrent_network.py
"""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from sklearn import metrics, preprocessing

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import learn

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.1
training_steps = 3000
batch_size = 128

# Network Parameters
n_input = 28  # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
rnn_timesteps = 28  # timesteps
n_hidden = 128  # hidden layer num of features
n_classes = 10  # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

### Download and load MNIST data.
mnist = learn.datasets.load_dataset('mnist')


X_train = mnist.train.images
y_train = mnist.train.labels
X_test = mnist.test.images
y_test = mnist.test.labels

print(X_train.shape) # (55000, 784)
print(y_train.shape) # (55000,)

# It's useful to scale to ensure Stochastic Gradient Descent will do the right thing

scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)


def rnn_model(X, y):
  X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, rnn_timesteps, n_input])  # (batch_size, rnn_timesteps, n_input)
  # # permute rnn_timesteps and batch_size
  X = tf.transpose(X, [1, 0, 2])
  # # Reshape to prepare input to hidden activation
  X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_input])  # (rnn_timesteps*batch_size, n_input)
  # # Split data because rnn cell needs a list of inputs for the RNN inner loop
  X = tf.split(0, rnn_timesteps, X)  # rnn_timesteps * (batch_size, n_input)

  # Define a GRU cell with tensorflow
  lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden)
  # Get lstm cell output
  _, encoding = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

  return learn.models.logistic_regression(encoding, y)


classifier = learn.TensorFlowEstimator(model_fn=rnn_model, n_classes=n_classes,
                                       batch_size=batch_size,
                                       steps=training_steps,
                                       learning_rate=learning_rate)

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, logdir="/tmp/mnist_rnn")
score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, classifier.predict(X_test))
print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(score))
```

Answer (score 0):

The logistic regression layer is used to convert the continuous multi-dimensional output to a "class". It is, notionally, what converts the inputs to a index (class label).

The intermediate outputs convey more information about the data, and they can be used for other tasks, but to classify samples, the logistic regression layer should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The code you attached *is* using the last state of the RNN. As per the documentation of [rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#rnn), the second return value is the state of the RNN after performing the calculation.

The [logistic regression](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9230423668770036179a72414482d45ddde40a3b/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/models.py#L171) is used to project the real-valued state of LSTM to a class, as well as to define loss function.